# Angular App very slow to refresh in browser after editing typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, browser-sync

I'm working on a simple angular project locally. To run it I use

```
npm start
```

giving me this output

```
> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start /Applications/dev/startupbooks
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 

[1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
[1] ** browser-sync config **
[1] { injectChanges: false,
[1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
[1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
[1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
[1] [BS] Access URLs:
[1]  --------------------------------------
[1]        Local: http://localhost:3002
[1]     External: http://192.168.0.157:3002
[1]  --------------------------------------
[1]           UI: http://localhost:3003
[1]  UI External: http://192.168.0.157:3003
[1]  --------------------------------------
[1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
[1] [BS] Watching files...
```

When I edit the typescript files it takes about 10 seconds to see the change, recompile the typescript and refresh the browser with browsersync.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Can I force the typescript to recompile on save ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running your cmd in Administrator?

Comment: You can use filewatchers in gulp to recompile them

Comment: Yes im running as admin

Comment: I'm using file watcher,  but it's very slow, i believe it should not be this slow. Take over 10secods to pick up changes

Comment: So I switched from sublime to atom and installed the typescript compiler plugin. Very responsive now , 1 to 2 seconds

Comment: So you've fixed the problem?